# Network Service Account not Inherited in ACL

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, permissions, access-control-list

I have a problem with files that are being moved into a folder that is set to replace permissions on child objects for the Network Service account. The process is that a media file is uploaded to a website, and is encoded by a piece of software. This moves the file to a folder but for some reason the files that get moved there don't inherit the Network Service account in security permissions. If I manually move a file into the folder the permission is inherited. I have used the effective permissions tool to check the Network Service account security permissions on the parent folder but this shows that there is nothing overriding it - the account has full permissions.

Can try and supply more info if required, but any answers grealty appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using PHP? Basically when you CREATE a new file, it will inherit the permissions. But if you create it in some temp folder, and then move it to your media folder, it wont inherit them, so you would need to copy it to get these.
Simply, on your temp folder put the same permissions and that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for this, it did help although PHP is not being used. Although it was fixed with a complete rebuild of the server in the end (problems re-installing IIS prompted this) I do suspect that it was because a file was being moved from a TEMP directory that the encoding software was outputting the file to before moving it to the final location.

Comment: Good to know you are not using domain administrator account for this, like me